# What other services are required for the Volume Shadow Copy service to start?

Tags: volume-shadow-copy

For some reason, the Volume Shadow Copy service is stopping. I figure that it could be because one or several other services are stopped. I have recently disinfected the computer from a malware, and during the troubleshoot I have stopped and started several of the services by using the `msconfig` command and the diagnostic start option.

So I'm thinking that this might have overthrown some of my services. I have set the option back to normal Windows start but my experience is that some of these services are stubborn and will not start again after stopping them manually or after using the diagnostic start option.

I was unable to find any information about this in the TechNet Library.

What happens if I start it manually is that it will run for some time and then stop without notice.

Comment: What does the Dependencies information on the service say?

Comment: I did a search for Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS) dependencies but couldn't find any relevant information. Most of the articles discuss software development and implementations. But you reminded me that I can find this information in the Services snap-in component of the MMC by viewing the service properties. RPC is listed there, but it is not running. Also, VSS is set to start manually. The reson for this could be that this is Home Premium edition of Vista which does not fully utilize Shadow Copy, in fact it's not even listed as a feature of this edition.

Comment: I will try starting the RPC service and take it from there. Your comment helped answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I was referring to the properties.

Comment: This old thread popped up because of your edit.  It looks like you may have solved the problem, or it was overtaken by events.  But one common problem hasn't been well documented, and I ran into it when using Win 7 years ago..  In additional to Volume Shadow Copy being started and set to automatic, the service Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider must also be started and set to automatic.  That dependency wasn't well published.

Answer (score 0):

to find the dependant services for any service - shadow copy included - go to:

Start > run > services.msc > find your service and right click > properties.  You will see a dependencies tab which will give you what you need.

It will also show which services rely on the one you are stusying too.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, on Windows 7, at least, on top of what the Dependencies tab gives you, be aware that interrupting the Server service will halt Volume Shadow Copy as well - so you'll want to leave Server enabled.

Comment: Not saying you are wrong, but this answer would be better if you could [edit] it to add a reference for your claim. Welcome to Super User.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, as It is a personal observation, I have no reference to back up my claims.

Comment: Personal experience and observations can certainly be a valid basis for an answer. However, in such a case, you may want to qualify your statement with something like "in my experience, ...". Especially in cases like this, seeing as the question doesn't specify a version of Windows, specifying the conditions of those observations, can also be a good idea. So don't just say "doing X will cause Y", but do say "in my experience, doing X on Windows Y will cause Z".

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for the guidance, edited the answer accordingly.